# How to correctly translate mouse coords to opengl coords?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I need to make a game for a project on college. Everything works fine, the only problem is translating mouse coords (0,0 in top left corner) to openGL coords (0,0 in center of the screen).

In class we got the formula for doing this:
double openglX = ((double)x - [half horizontal res]) / [horizontal res] * [horizontal opengl range];
double openglY = -((double)y - [half vertical res]) / [vertical res] * [vertical opengl range];

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define NDEBUG
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

const int GAME_LOGIC_REFRESH_TIME = 10;



/* GLUT callback Handlers */
void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float)width / (float)height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void gameLogic(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {

    }
    else if(value==1)
    {

    }   
}
void move_ship(int x, int y)
{
    double openglX = ((double)x - 600) / 1200 * 46;
    double openglY = -((double)y - 500) / 1000 * 38;
    player.SetPosition(openglX);


}

/* helper functions for settings options and parameters */
void InitGLUTScene(const char* window_name)
{
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 1000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(40, 40);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

    glutCreateWindow(window_name);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void SetCallbackFunctions()
{
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutTimerFunc(GAME_LOGIC_REFRESH_TIME, gameLogic, 0);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(move_ship);
}

void SetObjectsPositions()
{

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    InitGLUTScene("Space Invaders");

    SetCallbackFunctions();
    SetObjectsPositions();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Calculations in move_ship are quite good close to center of the screen, but at the edges they are off enough, that it's a big problem and the player can't reach the edge of the screen.

Comment: The formula converts screen coords into OpenGL clip space which is [-1, 1] for x, y, and z axis. (z-axis -> depth value). (z axis is left out in your formula.) It doesn't consider perspective transformation which you achieve with `glFrustum()`. There are two solutions to come around this: [3D picking](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial29/tutorial29.html) or transform mouse coordinates into a beam segment used for intersection on CPU side: [How to convert world to screen coordinates and vice versa](http://webglfactory.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-convert-world-to-screen.html).

Comment: That's a thing that baffled me. Everywhere i look i see [-1, 1] range on x and y, yet in every piece of code in college its in some werid numbers like I presented to you.

Comment: OK, so i did the right thing and abandoned some of the magic numbers, but the two left i dont know how to get rid of
```c++
double openglX = ((double)x - glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2) / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) * 46;
 double openglY = -((double)y - glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2) / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) * 38;
```
46 is width of initial X axis with center in the middle
38 is width of initial Y axis with center in the middle

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is you have some magical numbers in your method move_ship() . Your callback resize() is able to change the width and height, so using constants in move_ship() seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yea, I know it's a brutal hack, but right now i just want to get the mouse movement on point, I do not plan to resize the window either. If I get the mouse correct and have enough time before deadline, i'll surely do it the right way :)
Also I these "magic numbers" are the cause of the problem, because i Wasn't able to measure these dimensions 100% right.

Comment: Okay 46 and 48, we don't know where those numbers come from. I guess they are supposed to be MaxPlayerPositionXY/2 ?

Comment: Exactly, nobody in the class told us why it should be these numbers (different ones). These numbers i got trough trial and error and on the edges of the screen they get off, so i can't reach the edge. Everywhere in the web I see OpenGL coords from -1 to 1, and here I have 46 and so on.

Comment: Okay we're never going to be able to solve the ptoblem just here. Are you studying game programming ? Anyway the main ptoblem seems to be that you're just copy-pasting code you don't understand yet, or even the concepts. I advise to read somr online documentation about the various matrices used in openhl. Make sure you understand the concept of a world, camera and projection matrix. You're lucky your game is just a 2d platformer, so no 3d or projections involved, that will make things easier. And name your variables and functions well, it will pay off. Good luck !

Comment: Nah, I don't copypaste. The formula worked in class, and I know what these numbers meant there, i described it earlier. Just now, when i made a new project and DIDN'T copy this from the first one and tried to do it the right way i doesn't work 100%

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be

```
void mouseToGl(
    double& x, double& y, // output GL coords
    double mx, double my, // mouse coords in pixels (0,0 is top left)
    double W, double H)   // screen dimension width, height
{
    x = 2.0 * (mx / W) - 1.0;
    y = 2.0 * ((my - W + 1) / W) - 1.0;
}
```